# Recieving Empty list via restTemplate.postForObject() while consuming a microservice

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, resttemplate

I have created two microservices - Microservice 1 and Microservice 2.

Microservice 2 - Returns List of TrainDetailsToReturn(object) running on a specific date and between two cities.

Microservice 1 - Consumes Microservice 2 and returns the same List of TrainDetailsToReturn.

From **Microservice 2**

Controller -

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/")
public class TrainDetailsController {

    @Autowired
    private TrainServices trainServices;

@PostMapping("get-train-details")
    public ListOfTrainDetailsToReturn trainDetails(@RequestBody AvailableTrainDTO availableTrainDTO) throws Exception {

       return trainServices.getTrainDetails(availableTrainDTO);
    }
```

Class - ListOfTrainDetailsToReturn

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.List;

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ListOfTrainDetailsToReturn {
    List<TrainDetailsToReturn> list;

}
```

Class - TrainDetailsToReturn

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class TrainDetailsToReturn {
    private long trainId;
    private String trainName;
    private String source;
    private int sourceDepartureTime;
    private String destination;
    private int destinationArrivalTime;
    private int fare;
}
```

Class - AvailableTrainDTO

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AvailableTrainDTO {
    private long source_id;
    private long destination_id;
    private String date;
}
```

**Microservice 1**

Controller-

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/getavailabletrains")
public class TrainController {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;


    //we take two stations and date as input and get a list of trains along with their details from the train-details
    //microservice
    @GetMapping
    public String betweenCities(){
        return "Enter source and destination along with date ";
    }



    @PostMapping
    public ListOfTrainDetailsToReturn availableTrains(@RequestBody AvailableTrainDTO availableTrainDTO){

        ListOfTrainDetailsToReturn list = restTemplate
                .postForObject("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/get-train-details" ,
                        availableTrainDTO ,
                        ListOfTrainDetailsToReturn.class );

        return list;
    }


}
```

Class - ListOfTrainDetailsToReturn

```
import lombok.*;

import java.util.List;


@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ListOfTrainDetailsToReturn {
    List<TrainDetailsToReturn> list;

    public void setList(List<TrainDetailsToReturn> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public List<TrainDetailsToReturn> get
}
```

Class - TrainDetailsToReturn

```
import lombok.*;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class TrainDetailsToReturn {
    private long trainId;
    private String trainName;
    private String source;
    private int sourceDepartureTime;
    private String destination;
    private int destinationArrivalTime;
    private int fare;
}
```

**Response from Microservice 2 to Post Request from Postman** -

**Request**

```
{
    "source_id":"100",
    "destination_id":"140",
    "date": "05/09/2022"
}
```

**Response**

```
{
    "list": [
        {
            "trainId": 12018,
            "trainName": "Dehradun Shatabdi Express",
            "source": "Saharanpur",
            "sourceDepartureTime": 1015,
            "destination": "Bangalore",
            "destinationArrivalTime": 1800,
            "fare": 50
        }
    ]
}
```

**Response from Microservice to Post Request from Postman** -

**Request**

```
{
    "source_id":"100",
    "destination_id":"140",
    "date": "05/09/2022"
}
```

**Response**

```
{
    "list": []
}
```

I have watched a few Youtube videos but can't really find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Before trying to answer your question, I suggest you to read this post on how to name your REST resources : https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/ .
I guess, some PostMapping you did should be a GetMapping instead (`@PostMapping("get-train-details")`).

Last things, I suggest you to look at feign library if you don't know it. You could replace this old RestTemplate :) https://www.baeldung.com/intro-to-feign

So for your issue, have you try to put a breakpoint on your microservice 2 when microservice 1 calling it ? To see what do you have on input/output.

```java
@PostMapping("get-train-details")
public ListOfTrainDetailsToReturn trainDetails(@RequestBody AvailableTrainDTO availableTrainDTO) throws Exception {
   return trainServices.getTrainDetails(availableTrainDTO); // breakpoint here
}
```

Could you post the full requests from your postman ?